# Referencing value of alert box

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to write a rule that conditions on the content of a javascript alert box. That is, I'm trying to fire a conversion script if the alert says "submission successful" vs "some error message". Can I access the string shown in the alert box so I can use it i.e. if alert message == "submission successful" fire the tracking script?

Comment: Can you use something else like `confirm()` or `prompt()`? Does it need to be a popup? Can you post some code that relates to this?

Comment: Are you initiating the alert? Because if you are, then surely you know what the content will be... Anyway, there's no JS way of getting the value of an alert. As @area28 said, you can get the response from a confirm() or prompt().

Answer (score 1):

You could override `alert` so that you could track what is being alerted. For example:

```
window.alert = (function() {
 var existingAlert = window.alert;
 return function(message) {
   console.log(message);        // do your tracking here
   existingAlert(message);
 };
})();
```

You would need to be able to run this code before other code called `window.alert`.